# Finding out the maximum RAM my laptop supports - conflicting dmidecode information

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I have old NEC Versa ONE laptop bought in 2008.

Not used frequently but the 1GB RAM in it is beginning to be unbearably low for even browsing.

I ran dmidecode on it and it says in the 'Memory Controller Information' section that:

```
Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096MB
Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384MB
```

But in 'Physical Memory Array' section it says:

```
Maximum capacity: 8GB
Number Of Devices: 4
```

Then when I opened the case I saw that only 2 slots are physically present on the motherboard.

In 'Base Board Information' section it says `Product name: MS-1642X`.

I googled for it and it says it supports 8GB, but I'm not sure if it supports it only if all the 4 slots are soldered on having 2GB installed in each, or I can put 2 4GB modules into the two existing slots.

Will it support the 4GB modules or only the 2GB ones?

Optional question: should I expect that a laptop motherboard made in 2008 support this much RAM anyway?

Comment: What operating system are you running on it?

Comment: @n8te 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. Planning to upgrade to 16.04.
(and the browser I mentioned is Chrome)

Comment: The 4GB x 2 will work on it. So it's just a matter of personal preference as far as whether you should get the 2GB x 2 or 4GB x 2.

Comment: According to the authors of dmidecode, "More often than not, information contained in the DMI tables is inaccurate, incomplete or simply wrong." But I looked up your motherboard and it is capable of 8GB max RAM, and it's also capable 4GB RAM modules, so the fact that your motherboard has only 2 slots instead of 4 won't make any difference if you want to go ahead with the 4GB x 2 setup.

Answer (score 1):

> I googled for it and it says it supports 8GB, but I'm not sure if it supports it only if all the 4 slots are soldered on having 2GB installed in each, or I can put 2 4GB modules into the two existing slots.
>   Will it support the 4GB modules or only the 2GB ones?

Quick answer: 8GB sounds about right, but 4x slots not so much. However, you need to check the rest of mb, including **the other side of the MB** to be sure. You could have seen only 2 slots simply because other two are elsewhere. Seen it before - most notably Alienware and Dell Precision models.

> Optional question: should I expect that a laptop motherboard made in 2008 support this much RAM anyway?

Answer is Yes. Owning DELL Latitude E6400 (mid-2008) with currently 8GB RAM. However, getting 8GB of DDR2 in 2x4GB will be expensive, to say the least...

EDIT: Also, need to make sure you're paying attention to actual motherboard capabilities - memory controller can use up to 16GB, but the hardware implementation may support much less. It's usually the case due to costs - slots supporting more than 8GB require more paths to MC.

Fun fact: in 2008 max RAM supported by Windows Vista 64-bit was 8GB. See the correlation?